# Tesseract 4.5 return multiple results for same image structure

Tags: java, ocr, tesseract, tess4j

Hello everyone i have problem with **tess4j** with Arabic.trainddata
the problem is when i get result two times the results were different
like this
**the first output :**

"| رقم القيد ? : 139\n" +

"18/02/2020  : ?التاريخ\n" +

"SYRIA H.O : ?الفرع?\n" +

**the second output :**

"رقم القيد ? : 439\n" +

"التاريخ :08/07/2020\n" +

"الفرع : ?SYRIA H.O?\n" +

the last raw is reverse and it could be for other raw in another output

please i need solution for make ocr always start read from RTL or to give me always the same result

and thank for all :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tesseract learns or adapts its results over successive runs. You'll need to clear its adaptive classifier or cache (via `ClearAdaptiveClassifier`, `ClearPersistentCache​`, or `Clear` method) to get the same result across subsequent runs.

Comment: thank u for ur answer , but can u be more clear about ClearPersistentCache method does it Tess Variable ?? 
and how to benefit from Tesseract learns or adapts its results over successive runs ?? :)

Comment: Documentation: http://tess4j.sourceforge.net/docs/index.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer and I apologize for the delay, but for health reasons